# Getting "observationInfo" in iOS 6 SDK changes retainCount of object

Tags: objective-c, ios6, automatic-ref-counting, key-value-observing

I need that instance of my class observe property of itself, so I set observing:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myProperty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil]
```

And in dealloc simply check and remove observer:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    if ([self observationInfo])
    {
        [self removeObserver:self];
    }
}
```

This project is under ARC and all work fine prior to iOS 6 SDK. But with iOS 6 SDK, getting `observationInfo` increase retainCount of object and app crashes after `dealloc` with EX_BAD_ACCESS (release message sent to deallocated instance).

What is wrong in this code? Is it Apple`s BUG or mine?

**UPDATE**
There is stacktrace:

```
thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x016b60ab libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release + 27, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xff000002)

frame #0: 0x016b60ab libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release + 27
frame #1: 0x016b6bd9 libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 555
frame #2: 0x02538468 CoreFoundation`_CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24
frame #3: 0x0253cafd CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1933
frame #4: 0x0253bf44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
frame #5: 0x0253be1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #6: 0x024f07e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
frame #7: 0x024f0668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
frame #8: 0x0022e65c UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
frame #9: 0x00001efd MyProjects`main + 141 at main.m:16
```

Comment: Not enough info to go on.  First, `retainCount` is useless, not helping.  Secondly, if you have a crash, post the backtrace.

Comment: I add stacktrace, it is only autorelease pool cleaning. My opinion is that problem in getting observationInfo. Each calling [self observationInfo] change self.retainCount (increase it, only in iOS 6 SDK). I think that it is very strange behavior, without this checking all works fine.

Comment: Is there a reason you are observing a property instead of simply overriding the setter?

Comment: There is many workarounds to solve this problem, but why this problem can be?

Answer (score 7):

When you call `[self observationInfo]`, it's retaining and autoreleasing `self`.  But since you're already in `dealloc`, the object will be deallocated before the autorelease pool is drained.  So when the autorelease pool is eventually drained, it tries to release your now-deallocated object and crashes.  You can see this in the stack trace.  Frame #2 is a call to `CFAutoreleasePoolPop`, which is a function that drains the autorelease pool.

Answer (score 1):

-observationInfo is not designed for this. If you really need to know if you set up KVO or not, store some sort of flag as an instance variable